# Universal Specification and "Terms" in Axiomatic Set Theory.

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I currently am studying Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes as well as his Introduction To Logic, and I have a very important question regarding Universal Specification in his Set Theory book.

First here is his **Universal Specification**:

> If a formula **S** results from a formula **R** by substituting a **term** **t** for every free occurrence of a variable $v$ in **R** then **S** is derivable from $\forall v\ R$

as well as his definition of a **Term**:

> a **TERM** is an expression which either names or describes some object, or results in a name or description of an object when the variables in the expression are replaced by names or descriptions.

In a lot of his proofs he **Universally Specifies** using examples like:

$A \cap B$, $A \cup B$, $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, and $\{a,b\}$

But in order for correct application of **Universal Specification** as stated above we need to make sure these examples are all terms. Are we just assuming all mathematical objects under our domain of discourse are terms? Why exactly are those above examples terms according to his definition? The answer can't simply be "Because they are sets and all sets are terms" since he **Universally Specifies** with them before we even prove they are a set.

as an examples he defines:

> $A \cap B = y \iff\forall x\,(x ∈ y \iff x ∈ A \mathop\& x ∈ B) \mathop\& y$ is a set

Then in the first theorem after this he specifies $A \cap B$ for 'y'

Comment: You can checkout different formalized systems online to see how one works with them. For example check out https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems28.html#cab . You see there that they define something as a class "term" and after they have a definition. After that you can substitute this class "term" into free class variables. Under this link you can read more about this specific system: https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html#proofs

Comment: "Are we just assuming all mathematical objects under our domain of discourse are terms?" No, *terms* are syntactical objects: in set theory they are "names" for sets.

Comment: Okay but In this book we are assuming our objects under study will be terms.. this allows us to use universal specification in derivation  involving those examples above.

Comment: "Because they are sets and all sets are terms" NO, terms are part of the language and sets are mathematical objects: we use terms: variables ($x,y,z$), constant ($\emptyset$) and complex terms built up with function symbols ($\cap, \cup$) to "name" sets. For the def of *term* see Suppes' *Introduction*, page 45.

Comment: The formula for $\cap$ above is the definition of the (binary) function (aka: operation) symbol $\cap$; it is made according to the rule for definition of operation symbols in Suppes' *Axiomatic*, page 17.

Comment: Please explain then why the above are terms and hence can be used in Universal Specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I have appended an addendum to complete the discussion).

The complication apparently arises from Suppes's style of exposition, bringing up a delicate issue and touching on it wherever it comes forth in his narrative. The question hinges on an aspect of the [theory of definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/). A general approach to definitions is a knotty topic in philosophy, we shall deal only with the aspect Suppes treats.

In his *[Axiomatic Set Theory](https://archive.org/details/axiomaticsettheo00supp_0)* (1972 edition, freely readable on the website), Suppes gives two criteria for a proper definition in axiomatic construction of set theory:

> **Criterion of Eliminability.** A formula $P$ introducing a new symbol satisfies the criterion of eliminability if and only if: whenever
> $Q_{1}$ is a formula in which the new symbol occurs, then there is a
> primitive formula $Q_{2}$ such that $P\rightarrow (Q_{1}\leftrightarrow Q_{2})$ is derivable from the axioms.

and

> **Criterion of Non-Creativity.** A formula $P$ introducing a new symbol satisfies the criterion of non-creativity if and only if: there
> is no primitive formula $Q$ such that $P\rightarrow Q$ is derivable
> from the axioms but $Q$ is not.

The motivation behind these criteria is quite familiar: We set up a formal system from bottom-up, starting with primitive building blocks. While we specify increasingly complex features of the system, we intend to prevent external elements creep into the definition of the system.

An assurance for our intention is deemed that each step be reversible. This is straightforward in the cases of equality (syntactically marking an equality by definition with a distinct symbol like $:=$ may be useful) and material equivalence. So, for example, if subtraction is defined as a new operation symbol via addition as

$$a - b := a + (-b)\tag 1$$

then, the expression on the left-hand side can be smoothly replaced by the expression on the right-hand side, hence, subtraction operation is eliminated, in any and every case.

Suppes points out that some condition is stated as an antecedent to many definitions in mathematics, which causes reversion back to the relatively more primitive stage to be not so smooth. A general form of such conditional definitions can be given as

$$Q\rightarrow (O(v_{1},\ldots, v_{n}) = w\leftrightarrow R)\tag 2$$

where $Q$ represents the condition under which the definition is legitimate and $O$ is the operation defined by $R$. This formulation, as it stands, does not allow us to reverse the cases in which $Q$ does not hold. Besides, it is not in the form in which the defined operation occurs alone on one side of equivalence to be eliminable (just as in the case of equality). At this point, Suppes seems to appeal to the tautology

$$(\alpha\rightarrow (\beta\leftrightarrow\gamma))\leftrightarrow (\beta\leftrightarrow ((\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)\wedge (\neg\alpha\rightarrow\beta)))\tag 3$$

Since a conditional definition is of the form $\alpha\rightarrow (\beta\leftrightarrow\gamma)$, we can obtain an equivalence that has $O$ alone on one side (substituted for $\beta$ in (3))

$$\beta\leftrightarrow ((\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)\wedge (\neg\alpha\rightarrow\boldsymbol{\beta}))\tag 4$$

This equivalence still has $\beta$ on the right hand side (boldfaced), but we can modify and make use of it for the cases in which $Q$ does not hold. Hence, we can convert a conditional definition of an operation symbol into

$$O(v_{1},\ldots,v_{n}) = w\leftrightarrow (Q\rightarrow R)\wedge (\neg Q\rightarrow R')\tag 5$$

where $R'$ behaves truth-functionally like $O(v_{1},\ldots,v_{n}) = w$ (in order to be able to employ the tautology (3)) and addresses the cases in which $Q$ does not hold. Suppes gives the example of a definition of the operation of division via multiplication as

$$\underbrace{x/y}_{O(x, y)} =\underbrace{z}_{w}\leftrightarrow (\underbrace{y\neq 0}_{Q}\rightarrow\underbrace{x = y.z}_{R})\wedge (\underbrace{y = 0}_{\neg Q}\rightarrow\underbrace{z = 0}_{R'})\tag 6$$

where $R'$ is stiputed so that the case of division by zero is handled.

As for the definition of the operation of intersection, a proper definition is

$$A\cap B = C\leftrightarrow(\forall x)(x\in C\leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge x\in B)\tag 7$$

However, Suppes's construction admits individuals (i.e., non-sets) as well as sets, in contrast to Zermelo-Fraenkel construction which admits only sets. Thus, a correct definition with respect to Suppes's construction should be

$$x, y, z\text{ are sets}\rightarrow (x\cap y = z\leftrightarrow(\forall w)(w\in z\leftrightarrow w\in x \wedge w\in y))\tag 8$$

This definition turns defective in case that $z$ is an individual, not a set. We can see this when we want to prove that $\emptyset\cap\emptyset\neq z$, equivalently that $\neg(\forall w)(w\in z\leftrightarrow w\in\emptyset)$, hence that $(\exists w)(w\notin z\leftrightarrow w\in\emptyset)$.

So, Suppes stipulates $R'$ as $y\text{ is a set}$ and obtains from (8) in accordance with (5)

$$A\cap B = y\leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge x\in B)\wedge y\text{ is a set}\tag 9$$

**Addendum**

The foregoing considerations are within the domain of the (object) language and metalanguage of Suppes's presentation of axiomatic set theory. The domain of discourse consists of sets and individuals (in a similar way Ernst Zermelo set forth), which provides semantic values to the items of language (terms and formulas). The valuation is managed by a function $\mathcal{I}$ that interprets the non-logical vocabulary (signature) and a function $\mathcal{J}$ that assigns objects in the domain of discourse to variables.

The following definitions are to specify the semantic value of a term; as for the valuation of formulas and further details, the interested can look them up in the textbooks on **model theory**.

We shall denote the value of a term $t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n})$ at a sequence of objects $a_{0},\ldots,a_{m}$ from the domain of discourse by $[\![t(x_0\ldots x_{n})]\!]$. Standardly, we have three syntactic options for terms:

(i) $t\text{ is a variable: } t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n}) = x_{i}\implies [\![t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n}]\!] = a_{i}\;\text{where }a_{i}\text{ is the object in the domain assigned to }x_{i}\text{ by }\mathcal{J}.$

(ii) $t\text{ is a constant symbol: }t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n}) = c\implies [\![t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n})]\!] = c'\;\text{where }c'\text{ is the interpretation of }c\text{ by }\mathcal{I}.$

(iii) $t\text{ is a compound term formed by an }k\text{-ary function symbol }f: t = f(t_{1}\ldots t_{k})\implies [\![t(x_{0}\ldots x_{n})]\!] = g([\![t_{1}(x_{0}\ldots x_{n}]\!]\ldots [\![t_{k}(x_{0}\ldots x_{n})]\!])\;\text{where }g\text{ is the interpretation of }f\text{ by }\mathcal{I}.$

Comment: Thank you for this, will say more when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a term is vague, the way it is presented, which creates some difficulties in understanding it. Terms are syntactical objects, i.e. sequences of symbols. For something to not be a term, it must be syntactically incorrect. For example, a=b is a term, while a=======b=c is not. It is purely dependent on syntax, regardless of what the symbols mean.